# ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.16.0.5', port='9200'): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))) Executing teardown due to failed bootstrap

Tags: cloudify

I am trying to Bootstrapping Cloudify on Openstack is done via Cloudify CLI. My base OS is Ubuntu 16.04 VM (100 GB Hard Disk, 8 GB RAM) having openstack and I am trying to bootstrap on openstack CentOS 7 machine(40GB disk, 5 GB RAM).

It installed most of services like Riemann, AMQP InfluxDB, RabbitMQ, Elasticsearch, Logstash. I checked it is listening on port 9200 but it then exited with below error

```
2017-05-21 10:56:21 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.create] INFO: Preparing fabric environment...
2017-05-21 10:56:21 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.create] INFO: Environment prepared successfully
2017-05-21 10:56:21 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.create] INFO: Uploading key ~/.ssh/cloudify-manager-kp.pem...
2017-05-21 10:56:35 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7.create] Task succeeded 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_task'
2017-05-21 10:56:37 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7] Configuring node
2017-05-21 10:56:37 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7->manager_configuration_eb78a|postconfigure] Sending task 'script_runner.tasks.run'
2017-05-21 10:56:37 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7->manager_configuration_eb78a|postconfigure] Task started 'script_runner.tasks.run'
2017-05-21 10:56:37 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7->manager_configuration_eb78a|postconfigure] Task succeeded 'script_runner.tasks.run'
2017-05-21 10:56:39 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7] Starting node
2017-05-21 10:56:39 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2017-05-21 10:56:39 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] Task started 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2017-05-21 10:56:39 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] INFO: Preparing fabric environment...
2017-05-21 10:56:39 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] INFO: Environment prepared successfully
2017-05-21 10:57:26 LOG <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] INFO: Saving sanity input configuration to /opt/cloudify/sanity/node_properties/properties.json
2017-05-21 10:57:51 CFY <manager> [sanity_472c7.start] Task succeeded 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2017-05-21 10:57:53 CFY <manager> 'install' workflow execution succeeded
[172.24.4.11] put: /home/osboxes/.ssh/cloudify-agent-kp.pem -> /root/.ssh/agent_key.pem
Bootstrap failed! (500: Internal error occurred in manager REST server - ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.16.0.5', port='9200'): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)))
Executing teardown due to failed bootstrap...
2017-05-21 10:58:17 CFY <manager> Starting 'uninstall' workflow execution
2017-05-21 10:58:17 CFY <manager> [webui_23eb4] Stopping node
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the Cloudify version you are trying to bootstrap, looking at the log it looks like 3.4, so I'll refer to this version.

It looks like you have a connection issue, in the sanity test of the manager.
It also looks like you are using a virtualbox and this may explain the connection issue, because the virtualbox is not configured to route the calls on port 9200.

I suggest that if you are really using a virtualbox, you should route all the relevant ports to it.
It might also be a good idea to check whether your Ubuntu VM has access to the internet, otherwise you cannot perform the sanity tests.

Anyway you can skip the sanity tests and bootstrap the manager without them by commenting the sanity node in the manager blueprint

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using cloudify 3.4. I am trying to bootstrap cloudify manager on openstack. My openstack is on virtualbox ubuntu and from Ubuntu I am trying to deploy cloudify management server using virtual environment

Comment: From cloudify-rest-service.log I checked that on same port other GET request were successful but one request got failed.